# BlazeLayout+FlowRouter+Bootstrap not rendering where told to

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I've tried half a dozen different ways to do this but i'm not sure what the issue is.

To start, here is a quick drawing of what im trying to accomplish:

What I want:
http://prntscr.com/br8xh6

whats happening:
http://prntscr.com/br8z8p

What seems to be happening is that my `.row .full-row` is being rendered twice, and the dynamic template is not being loaded into my `<div class="col-md-10>` as defined. Why would this be?

Heres my current code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container full-container">
        {{> navbar}}
        {{> middle}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="navbar">
    ...
</template>

<template name="middle">
        <div class="row full-row">
            <div class="col-md-2 left-bar" style="background:#800000;">
                {{> Template.dynamic template=sidebar}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {{> Template.dynamic template=content}}
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
</template>

<template name="leftbar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{> avatar size="large" shape="circle"}}
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<template name="usercard">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail thumb-dark">
        <img src="default.png" alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Player name</h3>
                <p>...</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Join</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="home">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each playerslooking}}
            {{> usercard}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="find_page">
    <div style="height:150px;width:150px;background:blue;">hello</div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("middle", {sidebar: 'leftbar', content: "home"});
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/find/:_id', {
  name: 'postfind.show',
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render('middle', {sidebar: 'leftbar', content: "find_page"});
  }
});
```

I've refactored my code several times trying to debug this, as I'm not sure how BlazeLayout is suppose to work with nested templates.

All input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, did you have a try at Blaze Layout root modification?

See: https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout#set-different-root-node

Comment: Yes I did. Apparently, BlazeLayout does some type of modification with the `<body>` tag. So, I defined a main layout template and did **not** include it my `<body>`. I then set `BlazeLayout.setRoot('body');`. I think its working as expected.